# some objects missing after applying load option

Tags: autodesk-viewer

For large model load, some objects are not displayed when zoomed in.

Viewer option is "Autodesk.MemoryLimited".

What option do you need for accurate expression?

Is there any other way than SVF2 Model Derivative?

Please give me a guide that can solve it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EceMj.png)

[Additional questions]
Please explain the difference between **BIM360 VS forge Bucket storage service**.

Answer (score 1):

For large models SVF2 is highly recommended, please try SVF2. No other option in this case.

BIM360 buckets are linked with BIM accounts, certain functionalities like auto translation and other BIM services are limited to BIM360 buckets.

Forge is very generic, it's limited in certain cases when compared to BIM.
Both have similar technicalities but are different products.